# How to fix 'Shapes must be equal rank' in get_updates function?

Tags: python, keras, reinforcement-learning

I'm setting up both a custom loss and a custom fit methods inside Keras for the REINFORCE RL algorithm following bstriner's gist (https://gist.github.com/bstriner/e1e011652b297d13b3ac3f99fd11b2bc#gistcomment-2310228), but I get the said error.

Any hints?

I'm trying to adjust Maxim Lapan's Pytorch REINFORCE RL code to Keras. However, the y_pred and y_true custom loss Keras requirements have not let me reach this perfect PyTorch/Keras port...

```
Class NN():
...
    def custom_loss(self, y_pred, y_true):
        log_prob = self.log_softmax(y_pred)
        log_prob_qvals = self.batch_qvals *     log_prob[range(len(self.batch_states)), y_true]
        loss = K.mean(log_prob_qvals * -1, axis=0)
        return loss

    def custom_fit(self, x, ytrue):
        print('FFP-BP = 1 gradient update')
        updates = self.optim.get_updates(
        loss=self.custom_loss, params=K.variable(self.net.trainable_weights))
        return K.function(input=[x, ytrue], outputs=[self.custom_loss], updates=updates)
...
```

My expected results are to match the (almost) same results when I hit F5 with Pytorch's code:

```
    logits_v = net(states_v)
    log_prob_v = F.log_softmax(logits_v, dim=1)
    log_prob_actions_v = batch_qvals_v * \
            log_prob_v[range(len(batch_states)), batch_actions_t]
    loss_v = -log_prob_actions_v.mean()
    loss_v.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

EDIT 1: Upon inspecting, when Python debugging, I can see that the value of the loss is correctly being computed. So, I suspect it's something with the params...